# How to change cursor's select statement by some condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Does any body know how to set different select statement for the same cursor? I need somethink like this.

```
DECLARE Temp_Cursor CURSOR FOR
IF(@TempVar = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT CustomerId FROM Customers
END
ELSE IF(@TempVar = 2)
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderId FROM Orders
END
OPEN Temp_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM TempCursor INTO @TempObjectId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
```

.... etc

I have found solution: `DECLARE @Temp_Cursor CURSOR
IF(@TempVar = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @Temp_Cursor = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT CustomerId FROM Customers
END
ELSE IF(@TempVar = 2)
BEGIN
      SET @Temp_Cursor = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT OrderId FROM Orders
END
OPEN @Temp_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @TempCursor INTO @TempObjectId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN`

Comment: or you could just use dynamic SQL...

Comment: I agree with @MitchWheat +1. This decreases the line of code also.

Comment: Thanks for your unswers. I have found some good solution here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/01/01/sql-server-simple-example-of-cursor/

Comment: @Kanavi - Here is solution. I have updated my question.

Comment: How is it even meaningful/useful for a single cursor to be iterating over `CustomerId`s or `OrderId`s (with it presumably not being aware of what type of `Id`s it's working with?

Comment: I don't wont to share my exact query. It was just example to show you my situation.

Comment: @Radislav, I think, you have got the solution but moving in wrong direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `IF` outside and do two different cursors, one for each situation.

Like this:

```
IF(@TempVar = 1)
BEGIN

    DECLARE Temp_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT CustomerId FROM Customers


    OPEN Temp_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM TempCursor INTO @TempObjectId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
    ....
END
ELSE IF(@TempVar = 2)
BEGIN

    DECLARE Temp_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT OrderId FROM Orders


    OPEN Temp_Cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM TempCursor INTO @TempObjectId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
    ....
END
```

---

Another possibility is to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Answer (score 1):

The complete query should be dynamic. That means the execution plan will come out at run time.

**Example**

```
Declare @SelectStatement Varchar(50)
Declare @SQL Varchar(50)

IF(@TempVar = 1)
BEGIN
    Set @SelectStatement = SELECT CustomerId FROM Customers
END
ELSE IF(@TempVar = 2)
BEGIN
    Set @SelectStatement = SELECT OrderId FROM Orders
END

Set @SQL = 'DECLARE Temp_Cursor CURSOR FOR
OPEN Temp_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM TempCursor INTO ' + @TempObjectId +
'WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN '
```